# ValueError on Sympy Derivative plotting on MatplotLib

Tags: python, matplotlib, sympy

When I plot the derivative of a function but I keep getting this Error:

```
ValueError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-ef3e1063b51e> in <module>()
 10 
 11 w=np.linspace(0.2,2.5,1000)
 ---> 12 plt.plot(w,n(d(w)))
 13 
 14 #-------------
```

Here's the value Error:

```
 1291       raise ValueError(filldedent('''
 ValueError: 
 Since there are no variables in the expression, the variable(s) of
 differentiation must be supplied to differentiate [1.34327798672064,
 1.34160708363643, 1.34001407851726, 1.3384937790803, 1.33704145035797,
 ...
 1.26400405534568, 1.26395971947622, 1.26391533256015,
 1.26387089455324]
```

Here's my code for reference:

```
A1= 0.03550277875
A2= 0.7353314507
A3= 0.3334560303
A4= 0.9269506614
B1= -0.004826183477
B2= 0.005808687673
B3= 0.01399572492
B4= 101.2182926
#w=wavelength
w=sp.symbols('w')

def f(w):
    return ((A1**2*(w**2/(w**2-B1)))+(A2**2*(w**2/(w**2-B2)))+(A3**2*(w**2/(w**2-B3)))+(A4**2*(w**2/(w**2-B4)))+1)**(1/2)
```

This part seems fine when I tried to plot it using matplotlib:

```
w=np.linspace(0.3,2.5,1000)
plt.plot(w,f(w))
```

It resulted into this:
[plt.plot(w,f(w)) output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRFvf.png)

But, when I use the derivative of the first function, the error occurs:

```
w=sp.symbols('w')
def d(w):
    return sp.diff(f(w))
#sp.pprint(sp.diff(f(w),w))

def n(w):
    return f(w) - w*d(w)
#sp.pprint(f(w)-(w*d(w)))

w=np.linspace(0.2,2.5,1000)
plt.plot(w,n(w))
```

Comment: `f(w)` when given a scalar `w` returns a scalar; given an array, returns an array.  Given a `symbol`, returns s `sympy expression`.  Where does the error occur?  Don't just paraphrase the error message - show the WHOLE thing.  Why do people think an error summary is enough? :(  And if they work, show the `pprint` results.

Comment: Hi, I apologize for not being clear. This is my first time asking for help. I edited the question so that it's more clear from your suggestion. I hope this helps you help me

Comment: It's saying that it can differentiate:  `[1.34327798672064, 1.34160708363643, 1.34001407851726,..., 1.26387089455324]`.  That's just an array or list of numbers, not a sympy expression!  When `w` is a symbol, `sp.diff(f(w))` works.  When `w` is a an array, `f(w)` is also an array, and `diff` does not work.  Some times errors messages are obscure; I don't think this is one of them.  Be extra careful when mixing sympy and numpy.

Comment: Saying it can NOT differentiate an array.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing numerical and symbolic computation, which is usually not a good idea. This is how I would proceed:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sympy as sp

A1= 0.03550277875
A2= 0.7353314507
A3= 0.3334560303
A4= 0.9269506614
B1= -0.004826183477
B2= 0.005808687673
B3= 0.01399572492
B4= 101.2182926

def f(w):
    # this is a generic function.
    # If w is a numerical type, it returns a numerical value.
    # If w is a symbolic type, it returns a symbolic expression
    return ((A1**2*(w**2/(w**2-B1)))+(A2**2*(w**2/(w**2-B2)))+(A3**2*(w**2/(w**2-B3)))+(A4**2*(w**2/(w**2-B4)))+1)**(1/2)

def d(w):
    # This function compute the symbolic derivative.
    # Hence, f(w) must return a symbolic expression!
    return sp.diff(f(w))

def n(w):
    # This function returns a symbolic expression
    return f(w) - w*d(w)

# create a symbol
w=sp.symbols('w')
# create the symbolic expression
func = n(w)
# convert that expression to a numerical function (ie, a
# function that once we pass in numbers, it will return numbers!)
numerical_func = sp.lambdify([w], func)

# generate numerical data
w=np.linspace(0.2,2.5,1000)
fn = numerical_func(w)
plt.plot(w,fn)
```